# Leaflet.js transparent water/ocean

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have a LeafletJS map with OpenStreetMap content, I am looking for a way to make the ocean transparent, so you can have a  something like this: https://codepen.io/verticalgrain/pen/LVRezx (but then for Leaflet instead of Google Maps).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

.map-wrapper {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/1500/1500) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 13
});
```

Is this something that can be done using Leaflet; if so, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Are you using your own tileserver, or are you planning to use some tile provider?

Comment: In leaflet, image layers have an opacity option, have you tried that? Or if it's the background color, like in the example you provided, you can change the opacity of the background of the container that holds your map via css.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I am currently just using OpenStreetMaps as tile provider. I would prefer to not use a custom tileserver.

Comment: @JDunken I tried that, but unfortunately, the ocean seems to be "baked-in" the image.

Comment: Would something like this be useful to you? https://github.com/andrewharvey/osm-hybrid-carto/